# Rails generating incorrect SQL from ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a simple ActiveRecord object representing an estimated time of arrival.

```
class Eta < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :stop
    belongs_to :vehicle
    validates :timestamp, :presence => true
end
```

In my database, I created the corresponding columns `stop_id`, `vehicle_id`, and `timestamp (of type datetime)`.

I have a rake task set up to perform operations on this table, but it is generating SQL that doesn't make sense. If I try to run:

```
for eta in Eta.all
    puts eta.timestamp
end
```

It tries to `SELECT * FROM eta`, however the table is named `etas`, not `eta`.

The pluralized database naming is consistent with the rest of the tables created from ActiveRecord objects and I successfully created a similar ActiveRecord object that works correctly.

```
class PrecedingCoord < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :stop
    belongs_to :route
    belongs_to :coord
end
```

In the rake file:

```
for eta in PrecedingCoord.all
    puts eta.coord.latitude
end
```

Comment: hahahaha... this one makes me LOL... convention over configuration has occasional hiccups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails sets the plural of ETA as ETA.

```
> 'eta'.pluralize
=> "eta"
```

If you have already created a table called `etas`, you can set this in your model:

```
class Eta < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "etas"

  belongs_to :stop
  belongs_to :vehicle
  validates :timestamp, :presence => true
end
```